Iteration of a graph approximation
The code below runs a model based on a graph generated by the solution to a system of differential equations and shows one with random 5% error added to the points. How would I iterate this process (say 100 times) and collect the data generated by each randomized graph? It seems I would have to create new models each time which would not be feasible.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate, optimize
import random

def dose(t, y, b, s, c, p, d):
  target, infectious, virus = y
  return np.array([
      -b * target * virus,
      b * target * virus - s * infectious,
      (1. / (d + 1.)) * p * infectious - c * virus
  ])

def model(D, b, s, c, p):
  solutions = []
  for d in D:
      solution = integrate.solve_ivp(
          dose, [0, 5], y0=[1, 0, 0.01],
          t_eval=[2.8828828828828827], # used to be np.linspace(0, 60, 1000)[48]
          args=(b, s, c, p, d)
      )
      data = solution.y[2, 0] / 0.01950269536785707  
      solutions.append(data)
  return np.array(solutions)

b = 0.00001
s = 4
c = 4
p = 2000000
p0 = (b, s, c, p)

np.random.seed(20)
D = np.logspace(-3, 3, 7)
z = model(D, b, s, c, p)
s = np.ones_like(z) * 0.05
n = random.gauss(0,z*0.05)
zn = z + n

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
  model, D, zn, p0=[1e-5, 1, 1, 1e6],
  method="trf", bounds=(0, np.inf),
  sigma=s, absolute_sigma=True
)

# (array([1.98458777e-05, 3.39383754e+00, 4.55115392e+00, 1.00007348e+06]),
#  array([[ 8.35308599e-10, -3.25230641e-03,  3.73469971e-03,
#          -5.22169803e-11],
#         [-3.25230641e-03,  1.28672442e+04, -1.47634805e+04,
#           2.06436797e-04],
#         [ 3.73469971e-03, -1.47634805e+04,  1.69398903e+04,
#          -2.36868204e-04],
#         [-5.22169803e-11,  2.06436797e-04, -2.36868204e-04,
#           3.31209815e-12]]))

Dlog = np.logspace(-3, 3, 200)
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(D, zn, label="Data")
axe.semilogx(Dlog, model(Dlog, *popt), label="Fit")
axe.semilogx(Dlog, model(Dlog, *p0), "--", label="Model")
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
plt.show()



What do you mean by "create new models"? Can you add an example of what that would look like, as a starting point?

So, the system of differential equations is defined by the function 'dose':
def dose(t, y, b, s, c, p, d):
target, infectious, virus = y
return np.array([
    -b * target * virus,
    b * target * virus - s * infectious,
    (1. / (d + 1.)) * p * infectious - c * virus
])

Here we have three variables:
'target', 'infectious', 'virus'
To iterate this process 100 times and collect the data generated by each random graph, it is necessary to execute the entire modeling and fitting process in a loop, storing the results of each iteration. That is:
First, you need to define a function to generate the noisy data and fit the model. Second, create a loop to execute this process multiple times {!important} and collect and store the results of each iteration.
For this, create a multiple iteration:
    ## Parameters
b = 0.00001
s = 4
c = 4
p = 2000000
p0 = (b, s, c, p)
D = np.logspace(-3, 3, 7)
sigma = 0.05
iterations = 100

# Storage of results
results = []

for i in range(iterations):
    zn, popt, pcov = run_iteration(D, b, s, c, p, p0, sigma, seed=i)
    results.append((zn, popt

This is the loop iteration that can help:
for i in range(iterations):
    zn, popt, pcov = run_iteration(D, b, s, c, p, p0, sigma, seed=i)
    results.append((zn, popt, pcov))

Model Simulation:
Solve the system of differential equations to obtain theoretical data (z).
Add Gaussian noise to the data to simulate experimental measurements (zn).
Curve Fitting:
Use curve_fit to fit the model to the noisy data and obtain parameter estimates (popt).
Repetition and Data Collection:
Repeat the simulation and curve fitting process multiple times (100 iterations).
Collect and store the adjusted parameters and noisy data for later analysis.
Each iteration adds a small random variation (noise) to the data, allowing analysis of how the model fit varies with the noisy data. This can be useful.
Surely if everything in the code is correct. That's only a idea, is not the 100% solver, just idea.
